# How to sort a List of Persons by first name, last name and so on?

Tags: java

I'm prompting the user to enter his first name, last name and age.
I use a confirm dialog to ask user if he want's to add another person then I display the names that he entered.

How can I sort the persons by first name, second name and so on ?

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    ArrayList<Person> list = new ArrayList();
    int i = 0;
    while (i == 0) {

        Person p = new Person();

        String fname = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter First Name ");
        String lname = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter Last Name ");
        int Age = Integer.parseInt(JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter your Age "));

        p.setfName(fname);
        p.setLname(lname);
        p.setAge(Age);

        list.add(p);


 i=JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog(null, "Are you Want to Add other person","Confirmation",2);

    }

    for (int j = 0; j < list.size(); j++) {
        System.out.print("First name : "+list.get(j).getfName()+"\t Last Name : " + list.get(j).getLname()+"\t Age : "+list.get(j).getAge());
    list.equals(j);

        System.out.print("\n------------------------ \n ");
}

public class Person{

    private String fName;
    private String lname;
    private int age;

    public Person() {

    }

    public Person(String fName, String lname, int age) {
        this.fName = fName;
        this.lname = lname;
        this.age = age;
    }

    public String getfName() {
        return fName;
    }

    public void setfName(String fName) {
        this.fName = fName;
    }

    public String getLname() {
        return lname;
    }

    public void setLname(String lname) {
        this.lname = lname;
    }

    public int getAge() {
        return age;
    }

    public void setAge(int age) {
        this.age = age;
    }


}
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Concatenate all parts of the name and sort using them them. Implement a Comparable interface in a Person class.

```
public class Person implements Comparable<Person>{
...
    int compareTo(Person o){
         return (fName + lname).compareTo(o.getfName() + o.getLname());
    }
...
}
```

Then you can pass list of such objects to [Collections.sort](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#sort-java.util.List-). If you have access to Person's class code it's better to use Comparable interface. Distinct comparator is useful when you are working with 3rd party libraries and you can't add implementation of a new interface.

Comment: Neat idea, unfortunately it won't work. Consider Persons with names `A Aa`, `A Cc`, and `Ab A`. After concatenation and sorting, this results in `AAa`, `AbA`, and `ACc`. That is, two persons with _the same_ first name are not next to each other in this sort.

Comment: You can add a separator.

Comment: Slower/more memory since it requires creation of a new string before making the comparison.

Answer (score 7):

Two ways of doing it are, either have Person implement [Comparable](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Comparable.html) or use [Comparator](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Comparator.html)

Using Comparator:

```
Collections.sort(list, new Comparator() {

    public int compare(Object o1, Object o2) {
        String fn1 = ((Person) o1).getfName();
        String fn2 = ((Person) o2).getfName();

        int res = fn1.compareTo(fn2);
        if (res != 0) {
           return res;
        } else {
           String ln1 = ((Person) o1).getLName();
           String ln2 = ((Person) o2).getLName();
           return ln1.compareTo(ln2);
        }
});
```

(Just add this before your for loop)

You can figure out how to use Comparable yourself now

Answer (score 1):

If you are using Java 8, you can use [`Comparator.comparing`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Comparator.html#comparing-java.util.function.Function-) to specify what method to use for comparison, and [`thenComparing`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Comparator.html#thenComparing-java.util.function.Function-) to specify what method to use in case of a tie, and so on.

```
Collections.sort(persons, Comparator.comparing(Person::getfName)
                                    .thenComparing(Person::getLname)
                                    .thenComparing(Person::getAge));
```

Or make `Person` a `Comparable` using the same approach:

```
public class Person implements Comparable<Person> {

    // ... more code

    @Override
    public int compareTo(Person other) {
        return Comparator.comparing(Person::getfName)
                         .thenComparing(Person::getLname)
                         .thenComparing(Person::getAge)
                         .compare(this, other);
    }

}
```